# SQL Server: query to get data from both same table and another table

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables

contract master

| ContractId | contract Name | PlanCode | parentcontractId | IsCompleted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | contract 01 | master plan 01 | 0 | true |
| 2 | contract 01 | exterior plan 01 | 1 |  |
| 3 | contract 01 | interior plan 01 | 1 |  |
| 4 | contract 02 | master plan 02 | 0 | true |
| 5 | contract 02 | exterior plan 02 | 4 |  |
| 6 | contract 02 | interior plan 02 | 4 |  |

contractsupplierassoc

| ContractId | ContractorId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 |
| 4 | 33 |

contractordata

| ContractorId | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 22 | acme contractor |
| 33 | real contractor |

I want a query which gives me result like

| exterior plan code | interior plan code | Contractor name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| exterior plan 01 | interior plan 01 | acme contractor |
| exterior plan 02 | interior plan 02 | real contractor |

How do I do it?

So far what I have done is to get the interior and exterior plancodes on single table

```
select a.PlanCode, b.PlanCode 
from contractmaster a 
join contractmaster b on a.ContractId = b.ParentContractId 
where a.IsCompleted = 1
```

How do I join the contractordata using the contractsupplierassoc?

Comment: How do you decide which is the exterior and which the interior code? Do we just assume `PlanCode` starts with `exterior` or `interior` respectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, you might have to alter based on what your objects actually look like. This join path was actually quite simple.

Here's a real bad visual aid for you

[image]

```
select 
    cm.PlanCode
    ,b.PlanCode 
    , cd.[Contractor name]
from 
    contractmaster cm 
    join contractmaster b on cm.ContractId=b.ParentContractId 
    join contractsupplierassoc csa ON cm.ContractID = csa.ContractID
    join contractordata cd ON csa.ContractorId = cd.ContractorId
where 
    a.IsCompleted=1
```

Comment: The visual was just fine  :)